# Custom framework development with COCOA POD

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm creating a custom framework which uses Cocoa Pod internally. After installing POD I cannot make use of framework using agreegate target.

I added framework project with my application project just by trag and drop it inside Application project and linked it using Aggregate Target. After installing POD with custom framework, I can not make use the above mentioned way to link framework with my aggregate project.

Thanks

Comment: So your developing a framework that reference other pods. That shouldn't be a problem. Is there an error or a warning somewhere? Showing some code, some settings, sceenshot or error message might help.

Comment: @FlorianBurel I have been working on Creating a Dependent Development Project. So I cannot Install pod on framework Code.

Comment: raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios - Use this link Under title - "Creating a Dependent Development Project" - I want to add POD for Framework Sorce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developping a standalone librairy, something that users will have to add manually in their project, you CANNOT use cocoapod in your librairy project. No way! You'll have to provide your users with an install procedure indicating all extra step (framework install, project settings modification, pods to install) they'll have to follow to get your framework up and running.

This is why nowaday people use dependency manager like cocoapods. It makes it easier for users to install their product and install automaticly the dependencies.

If you are planning to distribute your framework thru pod, then follow the recommanded step to create your project architecture and reference in the example project (that uses pods) your dependencies.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios -  I have followed this link to create a Dependent Development Project . But I want to add pod In framework source code.

Comment: This is to create a static / standalone library. You cannot add pods to it. If you want to create a pod library, please follow this link : https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

Comment: I have created a framework, It has UI part also, So I have used "Masonry" Pod file for Constraint setting in UI. When Creating a Dependent Development Project , I cannot install the same POD there.        My Question is , It is possible to add pod File into static framework file, when Framework is in developing mode

Comment: The framework should not add the pod. When you are creating your project, add YOUR framework in it, then install your pods on the host project. In you static library, add the pod's file source WITHOUT using cocoapods (just download them from github and copy them into your project). Make sure to NOT include those file in the compiled library

Comment: Buel Thank you for your Answer, I got clear from you.